# R function Studio about retention time or in SQL program

Tags: sql, r

Can someone help me with a calculation of retention time? I would like the result to be

[image: data table]

For grouping by weeks, I can do it with SQL

```
select datepart(week, Order_date) as Weeks
sum(Quantity) as Jumlah_Order 
from sales group by datepart(week, order_date)
```

However, I'm stuck with how to do an R program or SQL calculation. thank you

Comment: For R help, please post a few rows of sample data in valid R syntax. `dput()` can be helpful, it creates a copy/pasteable definition of any existing data you have, e.g., `dput(sample_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows of sample data. It's very hard to test solutions on a screenshot of table.

Comment: i'll try ur recommendation. thankyou for helping

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess here, data in absentia.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
yourdata %>%
  group_by(Weeks = week(Order_date)) %>%
  summarize(Jumlah_Order = sum(Quantity))
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(yourdata)
yourdata[, .(Jumlah_Order=sum(Quantity)),
         by = .(Weeks = as.POSIXlt(Order_date)$yday %/% 7 + 1)]
```

### base R

```r
yourdata$Weeks <- as.POSIXlt(yourdata$Order_date)$yday %/% 7 + 1
newdata <- aggregate(Quantity ~ Order_date, yourdata, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: thankyou so much for helping!! but last i dont know about how to calculate cumulative on r

Comment: Please add data

Comment: yourdata = data.frame(transaction=rep(c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-26', '2020-01-27', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-17'),each=1 ),
                   name=rep(c('yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi','yoshi'),each=1),
                   product=rep(c("chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha","chacha"),each=1),
                   sum.quality.product=rep(c(5,3,1,3,1,1,4,2),each=1))